# Angular Typescript getter returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this class:

```
export class AuthToken {

    constructor(
        public email: string
        , public displayName: string
        , public expiresIn: number
        , public expirationDate: Date
        , public localId: string
        , public registered: boolean
        , public kind: string
        , private _idToken: string
        , private _refreshToken: string
    ) {
    }

    get idToken(): string {
        if (!this.expiresIn || new Date() > this.expirationDate) {
            return '';
        }

        return this._idToken;
    }

    get refreshToken(): string {
        return this._refreshToken;
    }
}
```

In a special case when I try to access the getter **'idToken()'** it just returns **'undefined'**.
I would like to understand why that happens, since I figured out a workaround but I don't get why, theoretically, it works.

First I show how I got the code to work:

1 - Call an NgRx action: (**userToken** is of type **AuthToken**)

```
this.store.dispatch(AuthActions.Login({ userToken: tempUser }));
```

2 - The action

```
export const Login = createAction(
    'LOGIN',
    props<{userToken: AuthToken}>()
);
```

3 - On the reducer implement a simple logic

```
on(AuthActions.Login,
        (state, action) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                userToken: new AuthToken(action.userToken.email, action.userToken.displayName, action.userToken.expiresIn, action.userToken.expirationDate, action.userToken.localId, action.userToken.registered, action.userToken.kind,
                    action.userToken.idToken, action.userToken.refreshToken)
            }
        }),
```

So the code as it is shown above works perfecly.

However if I do a slightly change on the **LOGIN Action** the problem occurs:

```
export const Login = createAction(
    'LOGIN',
    props<AuthToken>()
);
```

Note that <s>`props<{userToken: AuthToken}>()`</s> is now `props<AuthToken>()`.

The error occurs at the reducer when I try to access the getter and do the following

```
action.idToken
```

***It now returns undefined***

In the chrome console i can see the property _idToken but not the getter idToken().

Why does this happen?

Comment: Any developments on this issue?

Comment: Damn it was so long ago that I don't remember the solution but I think I found it :/